# Java Azure Functions deployment error: Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.19.0:deploy

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I have created a azure function in java created Using Command line by following below given Microsoft guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java

I have followed all the steps and locally I have deployed the functions and it is working fine but while trying to deploy into Azure using the following commands:

[image: error]

I am getting the following error on Command line:
[image: error]

Anyone please help me in resolving the above error to deploy the function into azure.

Thanks & Regards,
Preethi H R

Comment: looking at the error message we understood that its an authorization error. Could you please let us know do you have the contributor access to the function app?
If you have recently got the contributor access, try to re-login and do the deployment again.

Comment: Did you check this @Preethi H R?

Comment: @Preethi H R, please mask the subscription Id, object Id and official email id from the above image in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the user in my Azure Subscription and provided the **reader** role access and then deployed the function app from local to Azure using the maven cmdlet `mvn azure-functions:deploy`:

[image]

So, instead of reader role on the subscription, provided **contributor** role this time and checked the deployment which is successful:

[image]

**In Azure Portal**:

[image]

Not only the Contributor access, two more roles available

[image]

in accessing the Function App with specific privileges mentioned in one of the [MSFT Q&A Answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/669276/azure-function-rbac.html) by @*MughundhanRaveendran*.